# How would I approach to Web scrape across multiple websites to find multiple social media links?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I am planning to use Javascript. It's going to be multiple web pages so I cannot web scrape with a predefined script.

I would need to specifically search just for the social media links of every web page I input.

How would I approach this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe write a code to scrape the html file and go through every line to find lines with the domain names of social media websites you are looking for and save it in a file. I did something similar in python but i don't know much about javascript as i just started.